# ng-include not getting file name with utf-8 character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, utf-8, decodeuricomponent

I have the `ng-include` below, the file name it's getting contains an `ñ` character so it's showing an `not found error`.

```
<div ng-include="'{{mainCtrl.name}}.html'"></div>
```

I also tried using `decodeURI` like the code below before passing it to the `ng-include` but it didn't work.

```
self.name = decodeURI(self.name);
```

I already have `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">` and I already tested if `decodeURI` works in my javascript and it does.

Is there some way `ng-include` could read the `ñ` character?

Comment: What operating system? May be an opsys issue.

Comment: what is your backend language ?

Comment: My operating system is windows 8 and I'm not using a backend language, just angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically issue with `ng-include` use `ng-include src` instead.

Please use the following:

```
<div ng-include src = "mainCtrl.fullName"></div>
```

And in controller use the following

```
self.fullName = self.name + ".html";
```

Comment: unfortunately `self.name` is dynamic, I called it using https.

Comment: Update for dynamic value. Just use replace method after dynamic value stored

Comment: I don't think the issue was  `ng-include src ` because I already changed it to that before, but it only worked when I added the  `+".html"; `

Answer (score 1):

The workaround below worked for me, UTF-8 characters seems to be readable if it's called inside a function first.

**html**

```
<div ng-include src="mainCtrl.getName()"></div>
```

**ctrl.js**

```
self.getName= function () {
     return self.name+'.html';
}
```

Comment: the function will be called [multiple times](https://plnkr.co/edit/xwNqvcGTRpn8YLR3C6Fy?p=preview)